# How to get data from Viadeo with X-Ray and NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, web-crawler, x-ray

So I am trying to scrape some content with node.js x-ray scraping framework. While I can get the content from a single page but for exemple only for one employee I can't get my head around on how to get for all the employees.

Working Exemple but return me the first employee:

```
const request =require('request');
const Xray=require('x-ray');
var x = Xray();
x('http://www.viadeo.com/fr/company/unicef', 
    '.pan',[{
    name:'.pan-emp-name',
    job:'.pan-emp-pos',
    since:'.pan-emp-age'
    // job:'#profile #overview-summary-current ol'
}]).write('result.json')
```

Thank you so much

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x('http://www.viadeo.com/fr/company/unicef', 
    '#pan-emp .pan-employees .pan-empployee',[{
    company:'#company-info .company-logo-picture',
    nom:'.pan-emp-name',
    job:'.pan-emp-pos',
    depuis:'.pan-emp-age'
    // job:'#profile #overview-summary-current ol'
}]).write('result.json')
```

Working like a charm,

So now my problem is to get the company info